# Shadow Effect While Deleting Row TableCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, slide, tablecell

I want to add this shadow effect below the row while sliding the row to delete.

[image]

I am showing the delete button here in my controller

```
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(forIndexPath: indexPath) as NewNotificationTableViewCell
        let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { [self] action, index in
            sectionArray[indexPath.section].items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
               tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)

               if sectionArray[indexPath.section].items.isEmpty {
                   sectionArray.remove(at: indexPath.section)
                   cell.addShadow()
tableView.deleteSections(.init(integer: indexPath.section), with: .automatic)
               }
           }
           delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
           return [delete]
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SwipeKit solved my shadow issue with below code.

```
extension NewNotificationViewController: SwipeTableViewCellDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {
    if orientation == .right {
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        currentCell?.contentView.addShadow(offset: CGSize.init(width: 0, height: 1), color: KSColor.bwBlack.getColor(), radius: 4.0, opacity: 0.10)
        let delete = SwipeAction(style: .default, title: "enum.descriptor.delete".localized) { action, indexPath in
            self.sectionArray[indexPath.section].items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
            if self.sectionArray[indexPath.section].items.isEmpty {
                self.sectionArray.remove(at: indexPath.section)
                self.tableView.deleteSections(.init(integer: indexPath.section), with: .automatic)
            }
        }
        configure(action: delete, with: .delete)
        return [delete]
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsOptionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> SwipeOptions {
    var options = SwipeTableOptions()
    options.expansionStyle = .destructive(automaticallyDelete: false)
    options.transitionStyle = defaultOptions.transitionStyle
    options.maximumButtonWidth = 60
    return options
}

func configure(action: SwipeAction, with descriptor: ActionDescriptor) {
    action.title = descriptor.title(forDisplayMode: buttonDisplayMode)
    action.backgroundColor = KSColor.red500Base.getColor()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath?, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) {
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)
    currentCell?.contentView.addShadow(offset: CGSize.init(width: 0, height: 0), color: .clear, radius: 0.0, opacity: 0.0)
}
}
```

I also changed my cell type to

```
class NewNotificationTableViewCell: SwipeTableViewCell
```

and delegated self

Answer (score 1):

I think better to switch to use `UIContextualAction`. It's easier to customize than old and deprecated `UITableViewRowAction`. Refer this article: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/ios/uitableview-swipe-actions-ios13-swift-5/2256

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [
        makeDeleteContextualAction(forRowAt: indexPath)
    ])
}

//MARK: - Contextual Actions
private func makeDeleteContextualAction(forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
    return UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, swipeButtonView, completion) in
        print("DELETE HERE")
        action.image = ProjectImages.Annotation.checkmark
        action.image?.withTintColor(.systemGreen)
        action.backgroundColor = .systemOrange
//==> Put your shadow code here
        completion(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: my project supports ios 10 so this method will work for ios 11 and above

Comment: I see, how about using external library like this one https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit. There's some way to customize the action i guess

Comment: my code can swipe, show delete and deletes. The only problem is I could not figure out how to show shadow during this swiping.

Comment: I understand, i mean customize default control sometimes it's harder than using external lib